# Zeppelin Jackson version is too old error when running Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When running Spark Streaming code in Zeppelin 0.7.1 it will throw an exception saying that the Jackson version is too old.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace these jar files with version 2.6.2 and copy them to zeppelin-0.7.1-bin-all/lib/.

```
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.2/jackson-core-2.6.2.jar
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.2/jackson-databind-2.6.2.jar
wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.2/jackson-annotations-2.6.2.jar
```